# What to choose to begin with ComputerVision: Scikit-image or OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-recognition, scikit-image

My goal is to recognize specific types of traffic signs: red circles on video in real time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion OpenCV is better choice for you. You can find many tutorial for your goal. Here is a simple tutorial for beginners;

http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html

Answer (score 12):

Scikit-Image and OpenCV are both great for their respective uses. Unfortunately, as far as I know, Scikit-Image doesn't have the ability to do real-time video. OpenCV is much better for this problem.

If you don't know where to begin, here's a great tutorial series. It is exactly what you're asking, just substitute a stop-sign trained classifier for the face trained classifier. https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-face-eye-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/

Use a Haar cascade for the sign detection.
I found with a quick search for '*Stop sign Haar cascade*' that other people already have created trained classifiers like this http://www.cs.utah.edu/~turcsans/DUC_files/HaarCascades/

On the page, download *haarcascade_stop.xml*

Comment: Scikit-image can actually to real-time video; it relies on imageio and imageio-ffmpeg for this. You may need to be a bit more careful which algorithms you use, though, since some are implemented in python which makes them slow compared to a pure C implementation.